# MongoDB find query to return the first matching document, without matching all of them

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, bson

I have various documents in my Mongo collection named Product. *Each product is identified by a set of 3 keys. All these three keys together make one product unique.* I have these products in millions in my collection Product.

My system stores prices of these products. The user sends multiple objects in the request, and in each object it sends the three unique keys, and the price of the product.

I have a criteria where I need to find, that from all the products that the user has sent, is any product already existing in the Product collection, even if one product exists, I need to mark that request as duplicate and run some different logic of ours.

This is how one product looks like

```
{
   Key: "AGHT1876",
   Type: "P3",
   KeyType: "key31",
   Value: 23.98
}
```

The keys "Key", "Type", "KeyType" are the three unique identifiers together.

This is how my query looks like, to find duplicates of the request from Product collection.

```
db.Product.findOne({$or: [
{
   Key: "JKHT1096",
   Type: "P2",
   KeyType: "key4"
},
{
   Key: "YHU8389",
   Type: "P1",
   KeyType: "key2"
}
.....

]}]
)
```

Even if I find one object (hence findOne) then it means the request is duplicate.

But the thing is the request can contain upto 10,000 objects, and the query keeps on looking for all, then returns the 1st object from the iterator. **I want, that as an when 1st object is found, return it back and stop looking for other objects in the OR query**

Please suggest a way to achieve that.

Comment: Why cant you try with find().limit(1)  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7587

Comment: How do yo know `the query keeps on looking for all, then returns the 1st object from the iterator.`?

Comment: @SuleymanSah atleast that is what th documentation of first() method of Mongo java driver says https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/MongoIterable.html#first--

Comment: @Sarath: I did use it. Execution time of find(), find(). first(), find().limit(1) were almost similar.

Comment: @Mb-One but those docs are or first() method,  we are talking about findOne. Also did you have any performance issues? If so you can consider to create an index on these fields, Key, Type, KeyType